# Why do different rake commands affect different databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When no `RAILS_ENV` is specified, `db:create` and `db:drop` affect both development and test. However in the same situation `db:migrate` only affects development. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the `test` database gets updated via the `schema.rb` only when tests are run.

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#maintaining-the-test-database-schema):

> In order to run your tests, your test database will need to have the current structure. The test helper checks whether your test database has any pending migrations. If so, it will try to load your `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql` into the test database. If migrations are still pending, an error will be raised. Usually this indicates that your schema is not fully migrated. **Running the migrations against the development database (`bin/rake db:migrate`) will bring the schema up to date.**